# Can't install mist or pycrypto on python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

Whenever I try to run **pip install mist**, it shows me this error.

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
>   Running setup.py clean
>   for pycrypto Failed to build pycrypto Installing collected packages:
>   pycrypto, ansible, mist
>       Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: 'c:\users\utshab kumar ghosh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import
>   sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'C:\Users\UTSHAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c048vl5n\pycrypto\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\UTSHAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c048vl5n\pycrypto\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\UTSHAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m3uevb6g\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>            cwd: C:\Users\UTSHAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c048vl5n\pycrypto\

How can I solve this problem? I don't want to downgrade to Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Possible duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630793/error-installing-pycrypto-on-mac-10-9-5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102292/problems-installing-pycrypto-on-osx/10686297).

### Full Read

I know this is probably solved by [@Utshab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11697050/utshab-kumar-ghosh) but I recently had the same issue albeit in a slightly different scenario.

My problem was on Mac OS Catalina (unclear as to what's the environment of the question giver) and with `python 2.7` and not `python 3.6`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40095609/4890123) you need to install `xcode-select` which are command line tools for Mac OS.

Some people might have Xcode installed via the App Store, and can install the command line tools through the App Store.

Users who don't have Xcode, or don't want to install it via the App Store can use the command `xcode-select --install` to install it.

It's possible for command lines tools to be installed but the tools themselves (e.g. gcc) will still not work. This sometime happens because though installed, the location of the installation is not recognized by the OS. To check things have been installed correctly you can try to run `gcc --version` and see if the install location is similar to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

If you get an error about this `gcc` not being found you might need to point it to the right location so it will identify your command line tools installation:

1. Make sure `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` exists and has content in it.
2. Run `xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

After I did these steps I was able to install `pycrypto` using `pip install pycrypto`

Hopes this helps.